# Как реализовать локальные уведомления в Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, уведомления, android-notification, xamarin.forms

Вот что нашёл для андроида касаемо локальный уведомлений
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough
статьи как видно уже давно публиковались, может сейчас что изминилось и есть одно решение для иос и андроид? 
подкиньте кто-нибудь актуальную информацию по локальным уведомлениям хотя-бы только для андроида.

Comment: У вас проект `Xamarin.Forms` или `Xamarin.Android`? Тут смешивать не надо.

Comment: Кросплатформенный Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Если поискать на github, то найдутся различные реализации. Например: https://github.com/tmt242001/Plugin.LocalNotification